# Compare two zip files for differences

Tags: diff

diff command compares to see any difference betwenn two files. Can the same be used to compare two zip files, i.e if there is any difference in data ,like counts etc in individual files in the zipped files?

Comment: Is the order in which files are included in the zip archive important for you?

Comment: order doesnt matter, as along the correct files are compared

Comment: has anyone mentioned or suggested zdiff ?

Answer (score 29):

You will have to unzip them (if only in memory) to compare the two. A cool way I have seen to do this with `diff` is:

```
diff -y <(unzip -l file1.zip) <(unzip -l file2.zip)
```

That will show you if there are any files contained in one and not the other

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but adding `-qql` instead of `-l` to suppress some noise , and sorting by filename at the end `| sort -k4`

Comment: excellent suggestions @guido!

Comment: this compares the number of files. But what about the content inside the files?

Comment: I would unzip the zip files and create two arrays with the files. Then I would use something like `cmp` to compare nth element of arr1 to nth element of arr2

Comment: @UnixPhile
`diff -y --suppress-common-lines -W 333  <(unzip -lqq file1.zip | sort -k 4) <(unzip -lqq /file2.zip  | sort -k 4)` will suppress same entries and show missed/extra files as well as files different in size or timestamp. -W is about width, should be reasonably big for looong/path/to/files. Comparing by content will take more effort, let me know if that's really required.

Comment: Yes content comparison is also required, that will be a big saviour looking at the number of files to compare

Comment: @UnixPhile see my answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578867/49642

Answer (score 8):

I posted the longer explanation [at "diff files inside of zip without extracting it"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61113635/2063546) but if you want to compare the *contents* of the files within the zipfile and ignore all the metadata (timestamps in particular) then you should run:

```
diff \
  <(unzip -vqq file1.zip | awk '{$2=""; $3=""; $4=""; $5=""; $6=""; print}' | sort -k3) \
  <(unzip -vqq file2.zip | awk '{$2=""; $3=""; $4=""; $5=""; $6=""; print}' | sort -k3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to compare ZIP files and directories is to use **[zipcmp](https://libzip.org/documentation/zipcmp.html)** as mentioned in another post.

**zipcmp** works as longs as the ZIP archives uses the same directory structure.

If you need to compare 2 ZIP archives with the same files, but in one archive the files are contained in an additional subdirectory, **zipcmp** flags all files as modified, which can be a problem. So **zipcmp** can only used to verify if the contents are exactly the same.

I created **[folderdiff](https://github.com/ssh-mitm/folderdiff)** because there are some use cases where you want to compare a backup of you web application with a trusted source.

For example, if you want to find modified files (e.g. possible backdoors) you can use **folderdiff** for this task and can be used with ZIP archives and folders.

Example:

Wordpress uses a ZIP archive, where the files in the archive are stored in a folder called `wordpress`. In this example the files are extracted to `/var/www/` but without the `wordpress` subfolder.

**folderdiff** can ignore the `wordpress/` folder from the installation archive, with the `--prefix` argument and lists only `webshell.php` and `index.php` as different files.

```shell
$ folderdiff wordpress-6.0.3-de_AT.zip backup.zip --prefix wordpress/
===================== Added ======================
+ webshell.php
==================== Modified ====================
* index.php
```

**zipcmp** is not able to compare the files, because of the different path used in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Create a repository with some version control system (e.g. Git)
2. Unzip the first zip file
3. Commit the current contents of the repository
4. Empty the contents of the repository (except its metadata, e.g. the .git folder)
5. Unzip the second zip file
6. Run a diff (e.g. git diff)

Answer (score -2):

Checksums is the proper way.

```
diff <(md5sum file1.zip | cut -f1 -d ' ') <(md5sum file2.zip | cut -f1 -d ' ')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as if you add the same files to two zips files, but the file timestamps are different, then the file hash won't match.

Comment: If file1.zip and file2.zip does not use the same compression ratio, and have other differing options, the result would be invalid. Comparing zip files contents needs to uncompress the files before using md5sum on the uncompressed contents.

Comment: You might as well skip the MD5 hashsum computation and just run [**cmp**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html) directly on those files.